# Elasticsearch Update indexdocument

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I need to update an index document for an elasticsearch table and this is the code I have implemented. But it is not working, what's wrong and how should I implement this?

My code.

```
Map<String, Object> matching_result;
for (SearchHit hit : response_text.getHits()) {
    matching_result = hit.getSource();
    String flag_value = matching_result.get("flag").toString();
    matching_result.put("flag", true);
}

String indexString = JSONConverter.toJsonString(matching_result);

IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("index_name", "data").setSource(indexString).execute().actionGet();
boolean created = response.isCreated();
System.out.println("created or updated--------------------->" + created);
System.out.println("flag value==========" + matching_result.get("flag"));
return actual_theme;
```

(JSONConverter.toJsonString) is our library class for converting  to json string.
What is wrong with this query?
Instead of updating the existing document it is creating a new one. I want to change the existing one.

Comment: "It isn't working" isn't very descriptive. Please update your question with what is happening and you want to happen

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example code, it looks like by "update" you mean you are trying to replace the entire document. In order to do this, you must specify the `id` of the document you wish to update.

Using the Java API, in addition to calling `setSource` on the `IndexRequestBuilder`, you would also need to supply the id by calling `setId`. For example:

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("index_name", "data")
  .setSource(indexString)
  .setId(123)    <----- supply the ID of the document you want to replace
  .execute()
  .actionGet();
```

Otherwise, just so you know, in ES you have the option to do a partial update. That is, only update certain fields in the document. This can be done with a script or by providing a partial document. Have a look at the [documentation for the Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update).

In either case, you need to provide ES with the ID for the document you wish to modify.